# Codeigniter 3.1.0: Only default route is working

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, localhost

I will preface my question by saying I have searched high and low for a solution to my problem, including, but not limited to, Stackoverflow, YouTube and Google.

My issue: Only my default route is working in Codeigniter. My default route is set to a controller called Home which loads a home.php view. That works fine. I have another controller called Pages which as of now has only one method, Contact which points to view of the same name.

My routes.php file looks like this.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

// All custom routs go below this line.

$route['contact'] = 'pages/contact';
```

If I should change the default rout to 'pages/contact' my contact page shows.

My setup is as follows:

Windows 10
XAMMP 5.6.12
PHP 5.6.12

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it should be `'home/index';`

Comment: My controller is named home and the method is called home (I know redundant, but it works). My problem is the route called contact.

Comment: @stack-flo did you follow the class and file naming way as said here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: And did you try with index.php `http://localhost/project/index.php/contact` Make sure you have set your base url  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/3643/base-url-in-codeigniter#t=201609112325236778301

Comment: Yes I have. And the reason how I know my styling is right is that if I replace my default controller with 'pages/contact' my contact page shows. However, if I put it in the contact route, it does not work.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 http://localhost:8080/artisan/index.php/contact works. Why is that? I have set my base site url to $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/artisan/'; Why do I have to do index.php/contact for it to show?

Comment: I think you do not have a suitable htaccess out side of application folder you need to have a htaccess to remove the index.php https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: I also had to use  `http://localhost/artisan/` as my base url for my routes to work correctly.  Along with the .htaccess file.

Comment: Hey @wolfgang1983 Thanks so much for your help. Your answer and the github links you provided did the trick. I had to try a couple of them but I finally modified one that was able to give me the results I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Default controller name should be like this `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';` not like your `$route['default_controller'] = 'home/home';`

And then try it the url www.site.url/pages/contact is working or not if working then try 
`$route['contact'] = 'pages/contact';`

Also you can debug your route with [this link](https://github.com/PhiloNL/CodeIgniter-Route-Debugging).